# Move Microsoft Office to different Hard Drive

Tags: ssd, microsoft-office

I've cloned my HDD to a SSD, then I activated Office on my HDD, when I've put the SSD in Office isn't activated.
I've tried to copy the folder from Program Files across, but that hasn't fixed it.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don’t you just reactivate Office? I can’t tell if you activated Office before or after you cloned your HDD.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whta's the version of your Office? If it is retail version of Office 2013, Office 2016, Office 2019 or Office 2021, you need to uninstall Office from HDD first, then try to login your licensed account into Office on SSD. Any issues, you need to contact Microsoft team.